# Custom built module with simple message is not displaying on single product detail page in magento 2.4.1?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

So I've created one module to display "hello world" message on single product page like below:

However "Hello world" message is not displaying on product page.

My Custom Module look like below:

registration.php file look like below:

```
<?php 

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, //type
'Paymentblock_Ext', //componentName
__DIR__ //path
);

?>
```

module.xml file look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Paymentblock_Ext" setup_version="1.0.0">
</module>
</config>
```

catalog_product_view.xml file look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Paymentblock\Ext\Block\PaymentMethod" name="custompaymentblock" template="Paymentblock_Ext::custom_ptype.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

custom_ptype.phtml file look like below:

```
<h3>Hello World</h3>
```

PaymentMethod.php file look like below:

```
<?php 

namespace Paymentblock\Ext\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class PaymentMethod extends Template {  

}
?>
```

I've applied below command to see the module effects on product page:

```
php magento setup:di:compile
```

My module is in the list of enabled module as I can see here by applying below command:

```
 php bin/magento module:status
```

**However, I am still not able to see the "Hello World" message on single product page.**

**can anyone please point me out what I am doing wrong here????**

Comment: Sorry @AbdulAzizBarkat that I've place the image rather than images but I am changing now.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I've removed the images and add the actual code.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theme layout update file '/var/www/html/app/code/Paymentblock/Ext/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml' is not valid. Premature end of data in tag page line 2 Line: 8

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
        <block class="Paymentblock\Ext\Block\PaymentMethod" name="custompaymentblock" template="Paymentblock_Ext::custom_ptype.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Add `</page>`

Comment: Thank you for notice that:) I've updated my code and its working fine as I can see the effect of my changes. I'll mark bounty to you once it's allow me to give. However, do you have any idea how I can add HelloWorld message after Add to cart button?? like I have to change the name of referenceContainer from product.info.main to something else but not sure what I have to specify there to place HelloWorld message underneath of "Add to Cart" button?

Answer (score 0):

Run setup upgrade to set up the module : php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: I have already did that but its not working still the module is not displaying.